# Options for callback from python to c++

Tags: python, c++, callback, cython, ctypes

Hello i've been trying to call a python user-defined callback from c++ using cython for a while. But it looks like it's impossible without changes on the c++ side or a static function buffer.
So, is there only one option for binding a propper callback (ctypes with CFUNCTYPE)?

Cython 0.29.23

A.hpp:

```cpp
typedef void (*Callback) ();

class A{
    Callback callback;
public:
    A(){
       this->callback = nullptr;
    }

    void set_callback(Callback callback){
        this->callback = callback;
    }

    void call_callback(){
        this->callback();
    }
};
```

A.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "A.hpp":
    ctypedef void (*Callback) ()
    cdef cppclass A:
        A() except +

        void set_callback(Callback callback)

        void call_callback()
```

B.pyx

```
from A cimport A, Callback

cdef class B:
    cdef A *c_self
    cdef object callback

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.c_self = new A()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.c_self

    cdef void callback_func(self) with gil:
        print("I'm here")
        self.callback()

    def set_callback(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback
        self.c_self.set_callback(<Callback>self.callback_func)

    def call_callback(self):
        self.c_self.call_callback()


def print_():
    print("hello")

b = B()
b.set_callback(print)
b.call_callback()
```

Output:

```
I'm here
[segmentation fault]
```

Looks like [ctypes: get the actual address of a c function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635105/ctypes-get-the-actual-address-of-a-c-function/49635841#49635841) is a good one work-around, but it uses ctypes.
It scares me, but works:

B.pyx

```
from A cimport A, Callback
import ctypes
from libc.stdint cimport uintptr_t

cdef class B:
    cdef A *c_self
    cdef object callback

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.c_self = new A()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.c_self

    def set_callback(self, callback):
        f = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None)(callback)
        self.callback = f
        cdef Callback c_callback = (<Callback*><uintptr_t>ctypes.addressof(f))[0]
        self.c_self.set_callback(c_callback)

    def call_callback(self):
        self.c_self.call_callback()


def hello():
    print("hello")

b = B()
b.set_callback(hello)
b.call_callback()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think this requires an [mre] because it isn't a debugging problem. It could possibly do with a little more detail but I don't think it's necessary or helpful to be "complete"

Comment: We need to see the OP's code to rule out any possible mistakes being made in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function pointer does not have any space to store extra information. Therefore it is not possible to convert a Python callable to a function pointer in pure C. Similarly a `cdef` function of a `cdef class` must store the address of the instance to be usable and that is impossible too.

You have three options:

1. Use `ctypes` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34900829/4657412 (the bottom half of the answer shows how to do it). `ctypes` accomplishes this with runtime code generation (and thus only works on processors that it explicitly supports).
2. Use a `std::function` in C++ instead of a function pointer. These can store arbitrary information. You need to write an object wrapper (or re-use one from elsewhere) so it isn't completely pure Cython. See [Pass a closure from Cython to C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044063/pass-a-closure-from-cython-to-c/39052204#39052204). What you're trying to do is probably better covered by [How to use a Cython cdef class member method in a native callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187281/how-to-use-a-cython-cdef-class-member-method-in-a-native-callback/46204346#46204346).
3. Use the class C scheme where the callback is of type

   ```
    void (CallbackT)(/* any args */, void* user_data)
   ```

   and is registered with:

   ```
    void register_callback(CallbackT func, void* user_data)
   ```

   In this case `user_data` would be the address of your `B` instances (and you'd need to make sure it was `Py_INCREF`ed before setting the address and `Py_DECREF`ed before unsetting the address). [Cython callback with class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57875047/cython-callback-with-class-method/57876342#57876342) provides an example.